# Why that CSS :hover pseudo class not working?

Tags: html, css, hover, html-lists

i'm beginner and i try to design a navigation bar . i need to scale up item's size when it hover . I write css code for that but it didn't work. so i need your help

The css code i wrote mentioned below

```
.header1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 0;
    
    position: relative;
    ;
    height: 115px;
}

.nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;


}

.nav li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 30px;
    color: aliceblue;
    font-family: DejaVu Sans Mono, monospace;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    
}

h1 {
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    color: aliceblue;
    font-family: DejaVu Sans Mono, monospace;
    font-size: 30px;
}

body {
    background-image:url('bg3.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    margin: 0;
}

.header1:hover {
    background-color: black;

}

li :hover {
    transform:scale(1,2)
}
```

i need to zoom list items when it hover !

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove the space between li and :hover, like this:

```css
li:hover {
    transform:scale(1,2)
}
```